# Detect null character in string with sscanf in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, command, scanf

I'm programming a game which supports "new" commands, the idea is that when I try to verify them, I need to make sure that after the command given, there is nothing else but the null character in the string. I tried using this:

```
if(sscanf(command, "flag (%1c,%d)%c", &x1, &y1, &nullChar)) == 3) {
...
}
```

However, sscanf will return 2 always, meaning that the nullChar verification isn't working. How can I verify it? I would much appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: a `NUL` (and **not** `NULL`, that's a pointer) character is used for terminating strings in C, by convention. Generally, you don't want to examine anything after a NULL character because it does not belong to your string (and you will be reading out of bounds, likely.)

Comment: Right, but I need to verify that the user's input is not: "flag (A,1)asldkasldskaldskad because the verifications of position ((A,1) and flag command would work) but the sscanf wouldn't mind what is after that.

Comment: @userXXX: if the user's input is "flag (A,1)asldkasldskaldskad", then there's no `NUL` character in between. If there is, then no standard C function will regard the noise after.

Comment: You mean that I have no way of verifying that the string should end after ")" when using sscanf?

Comment: If the user's input is `flag (A,1)abc`, then `sscanf` should return 3 since the third conversion will work. So I dispute your claim that "sscanf will return 2 always".

Comment: why did you give the first character a width argument?

Comment: I tried what you said user3386109 and it worked perfectly! Thank you. Steve Cox, I gave a width argument because I expect the user to insert coordinates in ("letter","number")

Comment: Testing if the result is 2 or not 2 is insufficient.  Consider input "flag (A,1x".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sscanf()` cannot scan a `'\0'`.

`int sscanf(const char *s, const char *format, ...);` scans each `char` of `s` until a `'\0'` is encountered, then scanning stops without testing the `'\0'` against the `format`.

Instead, to detect if scanning stopped on a `'\0'`:

```
int n = 0;
if ((sscanf(command, "flag (%1c,%d)%n", &x1, &y1, &n)) == 2) && 
    (command[n] == '\0')) Success();
```

[edit per @Jonathan Leffler suggestion]

Whenever `scanf()` returns a value of 2, it is known scanning made it a least through  `"flag (%1c,%d"`, but not necessarily to `"flag (%1c,%d)"`.  By setting `n = 0`, `n` will only be non-zero if it made it all the way past `"flag (%1c,%d)"`.  Had scanning stopped due to lack of `')'` in the input stream, `n` would be 0 and fail `command[n] == '\0'`.  With a non-zero value for `n`, we can readily test if there is extra garbage past `"flag (%1c,%d)"`.

Comment: You should probably point out why you initialize `n` to zero — because it is crucial to it working correctly (specifically, it is crucial to spotting the difference between `"flag (x,12"` and `"flag (x,12)"`).

Comment: You could also do sscanf(command, "flag (%1c,%d)%n%*c", &x1, &y1, &n)) == 2 as the * blocks the return of the value so we dont need to pass a variable, and scanf would read 3 if another character was available.  Though this is a clever solution, minimizing format strings and using the posted solution is probably better, but AFAICT it should work in all scenarios.  You also don't need the %n in this proposal unless its used for other verifications beyond null-terminator.

Comment: @GregoryMorse `sscanf(command, "flag (%1c,%d)%n%*c", &x1, &y1, &n))` does not read from `stdin` like `scanf ` as suggested by "scanf would read 3".  Perhaps re-word

Comment: @GregoryMorse Strictly, this answer could have used the simpler `n = 0; sscanf(command, "flag (%1c,%d)%n", &x1, &y1, &n); if (n && (command[n] == '\0')) Success();`.  As to alternatives, consider posting your preferred solution.