# Allow all characters in a string with sscanf()

Tags: php, regex, scanf

I'm trying to parse Git tree objects in PHP. Since the format of a tree object is

```
tree <length>\0<data>
```

my first step is to use sscanf() to separate the data from the metadata:

```
sscanf($tree, "tree %d\0%s", $length, $raw_data);
```

Unfortunately $raw_data is never set as it should be. I need to have everything after that first null byte put into $raw_data. That could potentially include spaces, tabs, newlines, nulls, etc. because it includes the binary forms of SHA-1 hashes. So %s should be something like `%[<something that allows all characters>]`. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up getting just the length and then using substr(), but I think my question still applies.

Comment: Potentially helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987212/2943403